# difference between sqlite ramdrive 1m row single file vs multiple files

Tags: database, sqlite

Is there a difference to a sqlite db single file having 1 million+ rows and 10000 rows with multiple files if both are stored in memory ramdrive /dev/shm?

I'm wondering if i should partition my huge 1m row db (by category or possibly a-z letter and 25 tables/files) or if it would make no difference performance wise as its already in memory

This will be strictly used as a heavy/very frequently read only cache so file locks or frequent updates or anything like that is not an issue. If relevant, only run 1 query by PK id (SELECT * WHERE id IN (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

One million row is not that much. SQLite supports databases up to 140 terabytes. See [the detailed description of the SQLite limits](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

How much memory does the table with one million rows consume? It should be easily handled on any modern machine.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning makes sense only if the parts are on separate devices that can be accessed in parallel.
On a RAM drive, having multiple databases just makes all accesses more complex.